# cuda direct communication with screen

Tags: c++, cuda

Is it possible to handle UI directly within cuda code or not? For example let say that I want to write a program that do some calculation of size of some box using cuda threads and now that I have my boxes size, I want to draw them on the screen without send back my data to CPU.( I want to directly handle my screen from my kernel code without involving CPU) is it possible ? If yes how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to draw them on the screen without send back my data to CPU.( I want to directly handle my screen from my kernel code without involving CPU) is it possible ?

Yes, it's possible using graphics interop.  You are not drawing to the screen directly from CUDA code, but you can write to a surface that will be directly displayed on the screen without sending the data back to the CPU.

Look at any of the [CUDA graphics interop sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#graphics) for examples.

[This slide deck](http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/documents/1055_GTC09.pdf) has a detailed tutorial/example.